# NetBeans don´t run Node.js and ejs project what is valid start file

Tags: node.js, netbeans, ejs

I want to run a project which I developed with Node and ejs.
But there is a problem with the start file.
What musst I change.
If I start the project from the terminal everything goes fine.

[image]